# How to create a group of StackedBar using angular-chart.js [duplicated]

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-chart

I am using angular-chart.js, but I found problems to acheive a group of StackedBar, like this :
[image]

This is in below my code:

```
$scope.labels = [];
            $scope.labels = ["Janvier", "Février", "Mars", "Avril", "Mai", "Juin",
             "Juillet", "Aout", "Septembre", "Octobre", "Novembre", "Décembre"];
            $scope.type = "StackedBar";
            $scope.series = ['Series A', 'Series B'];
            $scope.options = {
                scales: {
                    xAxes: [{
                        stacked: true,
                        ticks : {
                            beginAtZero: true
                        }
                    }],
                    yAxes: [{
                        stacked: false,
                        ticks : {
                            beginAtZero: true
                        }
                    }]
                }
            };
            $scope.data = [
                [65, 59, 90, 81, 56, 55, 40],
                [28, 48, 40, 19, 96, 27, 100]
            ];
            $scope.colors = [];
            $scope.colors = ['#00ADF9'];
```

For the html code:

```
<canvas class="chart chart-bar" chart-type="type" chart-data="data"
                            chart-labels="labels" chart-series="series" chart-options="options"
                            chart-colors="colors">
                    </canvas>
```

So I get this result with that code:
[image]

Please any help

Comment: pass type as `chart-bar`. check this http://jtblin.github.io/angular-chart.js/#top

Comment: do u mean chart-bar in html code ?if so already done

Comment: Can you post a plunker for this? I will correct that.

Comment: Here it is:http://plnkr.co/edit/NznhWurqSgzhdzFNIu2M?p=preview

Comment: I posted an answer check that.

Answer (score 2):

Change stacked value for x-axis to false. 
http://plnkr.co/edit/fboi5UVLyBtS9ozo2QaR?p=preview. 
is this what you are looking?

```
$scope.options = {
                scales: {
                    xAxes: [{
                        stacked: false, // change to false
                        ticks : {
                            beginAtZero: true
                        }
                    }],
                    yAxes: [{
                        stacked: false,
                        ticks : {
                            beginAtZero: true
                        }
                    }]
                }
            };
```

Comment: Yes thanks but also for each bar, I want to have a stacked bar. a group of stacked bar

Comment: If I am getting that correct. You are looking for a mixed graph. @GhizlaneLotfi

Comment: let say that, how can I do it

Comment: I checked that but angular-charts does not support that as they only allow array inputs. @GhizlaneLotfi

Comment: Thanks @Sibi Raj, I will try to find a solution or to change angular-charts

Comment: Meanwhile, you can check. data-override options provided by angular-charts. I may help. @GhizlaneLotfi

Comment: Yes I checked it, here is my new code but still can't do it http://plnkr.co/edit/MzcrykfcxplUZOyhU8wZ?p=preview

Comment: to use data-override. you must use latest angular version http://plnkr.co/edit/Bs61jkGwFI9YiwIDjPXN?p=preview

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145423/discussion-between-ghizlane-lotfi-and-sibi-raj).

Answer (score 1):

The [latest version](https://github.com/jtblin/angular-chart.js/releases)  of angular-chart.js uses Chart.js [version 2.3.0](https://github.com/jtblin/angular-chart.js/blob/fc4e9a278e99fb1b6e605cdcfb037f47947e538e/package.json#L68).  The 'stack' datasetOverride option only became available in Chart.js [version 2.5.0](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/commit/eebaa84e72d82fb2ddf6075a7f21e0d1b9aa7b24).

There is a [PR open](https://github.com/jtblin/angular-chart.js/pull/676/files) in angular-chart.js to upgrade the Chart.js version, but it doesn't appear that it is being actively maintained.

So, the stack option to group bars separately will not work if trying to use this in angular-chart.js

Answer (score -1):

I fix this issue, by changing my code :

```
$scope.labels = ["Janvier", "Février", "Mars", "Avril" , "Mai", "Juin",
                         "Juillet", "Aout", "Septembre", "Octobre", "Novembre", "Décembre" ];
                        $scope.type = "StackedBar";
                        $scope.series = ['Vital épargne', 'Prévoyance groupe'];
                        $scope.options = {
                            scales: {
                                xAxes: [{
                                    stacked: true,
                                    ticks: {
                                        beginAtZero: true
                                    }
                                }],
                                yAxes: [{
                                    stacked: true,
                                    ticks: {
                                        beginAtZero: true
                                    }
                                }]
                            }
                        };

 $scope.data = [
                           [59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40, 65],
    [65, 59, 90, 81, 56, 55, 40],
    [60, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40]
                        ];
                        $scope.datasetOverride = [
                            {
                                label: "Vital épargne: réalisé",
                                backgroundColor: "rgba(99,255,132,0.2)",
                                data: [65, 59, 90, 81, 56, 55, 40],
                                stack: 1
                            },

                            {
                                label: "Prévoyance groupe: réalisé",
                                backgroundColor: "rgba(99,132,255,0.2)",
                                data: [59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40, 65],
                                stack: 2
                            },
                            {
                                label: "Prévoyance groupe: estimé",
                                backgroundColor: "rgba(255,99,132,0.2)",
                                data: [60, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40],
                                stack: 2
                            }
                        ];
```

Here is the result of it :[image]

check my plunker [solution](http://plnkr.co/edit/MzcrykfcxplUZOyhU8wZ?p=preview)

Comment: the link provided for the sample doesn't look like the output displayed or requested by the person

Comment: @NidhinPrathap I am the person who added the request and I answered my request

Comment: i am asking if you are have the solution bcz the solution that you mentioned doesn't work